# Form Creation - ASP.NET vs Angular.JS?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, angularjs

Good morning, I am developing a kind of internal form to the staff of a blog submit certain information that will later be posted .

The application is developed in ASP.NET using some Controls in Javascript .

The problem that arises is that I have a rented server on Linux and ASP.NET works only on Windows Server ( except in Mono) , but wanted something more functional on Linux, told me in Angular.JS . It will be the best option ?

Here is attached an example of a form to the test.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/mQp0jKL.png]

Thanks
Alex Ferreira

Comment: it's weird question. read about angular.js and asp.net. it's two different technology, and can't be replaced one by another. it's sound like, "i need to build web page. what is better chose? use javascript, or html, or i can use css?"

Comment: i already use a little javascript in this form to create some controls. my question was about the hosting problem and about performance. angular.js seems to be more lightweight with big data and later , wanted to make the form was created dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

AngularJS and ASP.NET are very different creatures. Angular is a client side MVVM framework with two way model binding. Where ASP.NET is primarily a server side technology harnessing the power of .NET and the MS product stack. If you need an app on a non-windows server you're right using ASP will be problematic (unless you wait for ASP.NET 6 which will be cross platform) but if you're used to ASP learning Angular is a very different mindset. You will also need a back end on the server of some kind (backbone.js maybe?) to provide data for the Angular app to consume and manipulate.

If you have the time for it Angular is well worth learning as it seems to be growing in popularity exponentially.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i will try to learn angular.js from scratch.Why Angular.JS will need a backend on the server ?

Comment: You need something to provide your data right? And something to save changes back to? In my case the app I'm working on now calls .NET API methods for this purpose but as you can't run .Net stuff on your server you will have to use something like backbone.js or PHP etc

Comment: Have a look at this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26445342/what-is-a-good-back-end-to-use-with-angularjs

Comment: Also I think I meant node.js not backbone.js... so many frameworks!